# How retrieve Discord messages to my website?

Tags: python, django, discord

I currently have a Python/Django platform and a Discord community. I would like to get the messages of a channel to convert them into notifications on the site.

Obviously I consulted the Discord doc but I really have trouble understanding. I don't want to create a bot for this simple action, in principle by using the OAuth app with the "messages.read" scopes it would be possible.

I can generate my token now:

```
def discord_get_token():
 data = {
   'client_id':DISCORD_CLIENT_ID,
   'client_secret':DISCORD_PRIVATE_KEY,
   'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
   'redirect_uri': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
   'scope': 'identify connections messages.read'
 }
 headers = {
   'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
 }
 r = requests.post('%s/oauth2/token' % DISCORD_BASE_URI, data=data, headers=headers)
 r.raise_for_status()

 #Token
 print(r.json()['access_token'])
 return r.json()['access_token']
```

Then the call to the messages with the following route /channels/{channel.id}/messages :

```
def get_channel_messages(id_channel):
 route = "/channels/"+ str(id_channel) +"/messages"
 data,error_message = request_discord('GET',route)

 print(data)

def request_discord(method,url_access,body={}):
   data =''
   #Call token
   error_message = ''
   access_token = discord_get_token()

   #Call request
   headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json','Authorization':'bearer ' + access_token}

   body = body
   if method=="GET":
       result = requests.get(DISCORD_BASE_URI + url_access, headers=headers,data=body)
   else:
       result = requests.post(DISCORD_BASE_URI + url_access, headers=headers,data=body)

   #Check result
   if result.status_code != 200 and result.status_code != 201:
       error_message = "Impossible de d'obtenir un resultat erreur: " + str(result.status_code)
   else:
       data = result.json()

   return data,error_message
```

A 401 error is returned.

Unlike most APIs, we generate our token and call the requests. I notice that Discord works a little differently.

What are the missing steps? Do I have to use a bot? Do I have to do a manual authorization with the OAuth2 URL Generator each time?

Thanks for your answers!

**EDIT :**

Generate token directly with user account :

```
def discord_get_token():
 data = {
   'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
   'scope': 'messages.read'
 }
 headers = {
   'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
 }
 r = requests.post('%s/oauth2/token' % DISCORD_BASE_URI, data=data,    headers=headers, auth=(DISCORD_CLIENT_ID, DISCORD_PRIVATE_KEY))
 r.raise_for_status()

 #Token
 return r.json()['access_token']
```

Comment: If you look in firefox network tools while on Discord. You see that you can use your user account token to call endpoints like /messages. You don't need to generate the access token. You are making it much harder than it needs to be.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Noah . Indeed I had done it at the beginning. However I had the same error (error 401 unauthorized) on the same request. So it doesn't really solve my problem :/ If I understood correctly I have to call the OAuth url generator link with the message.read scope which is a manual action in any case isn't it ?

Comment: I just tested and it worked for me. I posted what i did for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import requests
>>> en = "/channels/{channel.id}/messages"
>>> #channelid
>>> b = "https://discord.com/api/v8"
>>> url = b + "/channels/channelid/messages"
>>> url
'https://discord.com/api/v8/channels/channelid/messages'
>>> headers = {
    "Authorization": "OtokenhereNo"
    }
>>> r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
>>> r
<Response [200]>
```

The token can be your real user token. I believe you are getting a 401 HTTP code because you're trying to send a post-like request instead of a GET. You also have "Bearer" infront of the token which will not work. While this seems to be the answer, if you are trying to make a real-time message update system, I think you would be better off with Discords websockets API.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I just reproduced the same thing token generated directly with my client ID and Secret key, no worries about that. Then I removed "Bearer" in the headers, I checked that my request was in GET. I checked the channel ID, everything is ok. Then I did like you, test directly in python and get the same error. There is a missing step in my system (I edited the new function concerning the generation of the token)

Comment: Maybe my error is the  grant_type ? Or link between my application and the discord server?

Comment: you should not be generating any token, that is your issue. Go to your discord PC app and open the chrome browser, click a channel, look for the "science" request and copy the authorization header token. That is the token you should be using.

Comment: thank you very much! Everything works perfectly ! I conclude that this token never expires ! you spoke about websockets, before looking for this side there can we do it without going through a bot ? Thank you very much again !

Comment: your conclusion is almost correct. The token is a encryption/encoding of your login credentials. This means itll change when you change password or anything related to your login information. The websockets API is pretty simple once you get connected. That is for another question though. If my answer was right please mark it as correct.

Comment: you avoid rate limits and such using the websockets api since its only a few constant TCP connections

Comment: I'm going to take a closer look at this thanks a lot!